# How do you Show $x$ is a limit point of $A$ given you know for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a point $a$ in $A$ with $d(x,a)< \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a set $A$ in a metric space.

Given that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a point $a$ in $A$ with $d(x,a)<\epsilon$, how do you show/prove $x$ is a limit point of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\varepsilon = 1$, by assumption there exists $a_1\in A$ so that $d(x,a_1)<1$.

Set $\varepsilon = 1/2$, by assumption there exists $a_2\in A$ so that $d(x,a_2)<1/2$

...

Generaly, for $\varepsilon=1/n$, there exists $a_n\in A$ so that $d(x,a_n)<1/n$.

The sequence $a_n$ is a sequence of elements in $A$ and is satisfying that $a_n\rightarrow x$, therefore $x$ is a limit point for $A$.